# Phase estimation in contrast interferometry

Tags: atomic-physics, interference, interferometry

In contrast interferometry, such as an atom interferometer using atoms in different momentum states or a fiber optic gyroscope (FOG), the signal in its simplest form can be written

$$S=\eta\left(1-\cos\phi\right)$$

where $\eta$ is the signal contrast and $\phi$ is a phase shift that can be proportional to things such as inertial effects. When estimating the phase after taking a measurement

$$\phi=\cos^{-1}\left(1-\frac{S}{\eta}\right)$$

it would seem by the dependence of the phase estimation on the contrast that the contrast must be known prior to the measurement being taken. In practice, how is this achieved?

The contrast could be calibrated before measurements by scanning over a known phase shift, but this seems impractical, especially for atom interferometers that rely on noisy absorption images to measure the signal. The contrast can surely vary on short time scales introducing noise and so inaccurate measurements into the system?

Answer (score 2):

In practice, you need to be able to scan your $\phi$ to determine crucial parameters of your interferometer from fits, like contrast or transfer function. When you know those details you manually adjust $\phi$ to be $\pi/2$, i.e. you are on the slope of the fringe, where sensitivity to phase fluctuations is the biggest. In the atom interferometers, it is done by changing $T$ - free fall time between interferometer pulses. Finally, you are trying to keep all technical parameters stable and you observe how your signal is changing due to the external interaction.